# Substring of concatenated strings

Tags: string, substring, concatenation, terraform

## My Problem

Consider a resource whose `name_prefix` is too long. The name prefix is a concatenation of other variables, e.g.:

```
"${var.owner}-${var.role}-specific-"
```

I would like to use the [`substr`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#substr-string-offset-length-) function to make sure the resource name does not exceed 32 characters.

## What have I tried

```
"${substr(${var.owner}-${var.role}-specific- 0, min(length(var.name_prefix_full), 32))}"
```

Which failed with:

```
...Error reading config for aws_iam_role_policy[role]: 
  parse error at 1:10: expected expression but found invalid sequence "$"
```

## My Question

**How can I sub-string a concatenation of strings in Terraform?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HCL interpolation syntax can be strange, try:

```
name_prefix = "${substr("${var.owner}-${var.role}-specific-", 0, 32)}"
```

(If you need a `min` before the 32, keep it.  But the HCL behaviour of giving the entire string if it is shorter than the requested length usually means you do not need that computation.)

**Update**:

32 characters should be the *maximum* value. If the string is shoerter than 32 characters, it should not be padded.

```
name_prefix = "${substr("${var.owner}-${var.role}-specific-", 0, 
                min(length("${var.owner}-${var.role}-specific-"), 32))}"
```